# Does Fubini's theorem hold for this function?

Tags: real-analysis

The original problem is:

> Suppose that
> $$
> f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
> 2^{2x}&(x,y)\in [2^{-n},2^{-(n-1)}]\times [2^{-n},2^{-(n-1)}],\\
> -2^{2x+1}&(x,y)\in [2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}]\times [2^{-n},2^{-(n-1)}],\\
> 0&\text{others},
> \end{cases}(n=1,2,\cdots )
> $$
> prove that Fubini's theorem does not hold for this function, which means
> $$
> \int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y){\rm d}x\right){\rm d}y\neq \int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y){\rm d}x\right){\rm d}y.
> $$

However, simple calculations show that this function may be Lebesgue integrable, thus satisfying the conditions of Fubini's theorem. Here is my calculation process:

First, we consider $f^+$. For each area $[2^{-n},2^{-(n-1)}]\times [2^{-n},2^{-(n-1)}]$ we have:
$$
\int_{2^{-n}}^{2^{-(n-1)}}\left(\int_{2^{-n}}^{2^{-(n-1)}}f(x,y){\rm d}x\right){\rm d}y=\frac{2^{2^{1-n}\ \ -n}\left(2^{2^{1-n}}-1\right)}{\log(4)},
$$
Using Wolfram Alpha we have:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2^{1-n}\ \ -n}\left(2^{2^{1-n}}-1\right)}{\log(4)}\approx 0.853102,
$$
which shows that $f^+$ is integrable, so does $f^-$. Since $f=f^+-f^-$, we know that $f$ is integrable, so Fubini's theorem holds for this function.

I'm wondering where the problem is. Is there something wrong with my calculations, or is this exercise incorrect?

Comment: actually $|f|$ is bounded (at most $8$) on a bounded domain, so it is integrable... Are you sure you have the correct text?

Comment: @Exodd The domain seems bounded to me, as for example a subset of $[2^{-1},2^{-1}]^2$.

Comment: I've confirmed that the exercise is incorrect, Fubini's theorem holds for $f$.